How to add query string at the end of sitemap Yoast SEO
trying to add a query string for every products and product category pages onto sitemap so google can index them properly. My sitemap is generated by yoast seo plugin for wordpress.
This query string ?wmc-currency=AUD will direct users to a product page, showing Australian dollar as currency
I have a total of 3 different currencies, AUD, USD, and GBP.
A product link without any query string will be directed to the default page showing USD currency.
So what I am trying to achieve is adding extra URLs with query string to the default sitemap.
Is this possible?

If it's a sitemap generated by Yoast, you should check with Yoast's support team. Third-party plugin support is off topic here.

If you want to add ?wmc-currency=AUD for all of your product URLs in the sitemap, you can use the wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_url filter:
/**
 * Alters the URL structure for all products
 *
 * @param string  $url  The URL to modify.
 * @param WP_Post $post The post object.
 *
 * @return string The modified URL.
 */
function sitemap_product_url( $url, $post ) {
        if ( $post->post_type === 'product' ) {
                $url .= '?wmc-currency=AUD';
        }
        return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_xml_sitemap_post_url', 'sitemap_product_url', 10, 2 );

If you want to add extra URL for other currencies, you can then generate an additional sitemap, and then include that sitemap for indexing using the following code:
 * Writes additional/custom XML sitemap strings to the XML sitemap index.
 *
 * @param string $sitemap_custom_items XML describing one or more custom sitemaps.
 *
 * @return string The XML sitemap index with the additional XML.
 */
function add_sitemap_custom_items( $sitemap_custom_items ) {
    $sitemap_custom_items .= '
<sitemap>
<loc>http://www.example.com/external-sitemap-1.xml</loc>
<lastmod>2017-05-22T23:12:27+00:00</lastmod>
</sitemap>';
    return $sitemap_custom_items;
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_index', 'add_sitemap_custom_items' );

Reference: Yoast SEO Sitemap API
